# TYPO3 - Title of a content element to the page title

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to set in my TYPO3 instalation `<title>` tag based on td_calendat content element title.

- Database name with title - `tx_tdcalendar_events`
- Field with title in db - `title`

My code looks like this but it didn't work - it display only empty `<title>` tag

```
lib.eventTitle = COA
lib.eventTitle {

  10 = RECORDS
  10 {
    source = {GP:tx_tdcalendar_events|td_calendar}
    source.insertData = 1
    tables = tx_tdcalendar_events
    conf.tx_tdcalendar_events >
    conf.tx_tdcalendar_events = TEXT
    conf.tx_tdcalendar_events.field = title
  }
  wrap = <title>|</title>
}

page.config.noPageTitle = 2
page.headerData.10 >
page.headerData.10 < lib.eventTitle
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tested locally with `tt_news` table and it works fine. Make sure, that the record exists and that `tx_tdcalendar_events`is correclty added to TCA.

Comment: I also tested that code with tt_news, but it didn't work with td_calendar. I checked TCA and everything looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

> source = {GP:tx_tdcalendar_events|td_calendar}

To this:

> source = {GP:tx_tdcalendar_pi1|event}

You are transfering data in your link as tx_tdcalendar_pi1 variables, you need to use "event" id to get the correct event title.